# How to: Upgrade an ASP.NET Web Application to ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net

I have one app that is base on asp.net mvc4, I want update it to the asp.net5, I have downloaded VS2015 and used it to loaded my app, however, no see any change, what can I do?

Comment: Are you going to convert MVC 4 project to web application project with asp.net 5 (not mvc 5?)

Comment: Hey Lali, it should be asp.net MVC5.